# my laptop is getting hang after installing ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 recently, my laptop gets hanged after an hour and nothing works. 
Only i can do is press power button every time to shutdown and restart it.
Any solution for this?

Comment: System specs? Temperatures? Log files?

Answer (score 1):

This could happen for a variety of reasons. First step is to search the log files for an event on the same time the computer crashed.

I would start with the system log.

```
less /var/log/syslog
```

And secondly with the fail log

```
less /var/log/faillog
```

You can also use nano or vim to read these logs in terminal. But for some you may have to use sudo.

```
nano /var/log/syslog
```